# Call PInvoke with std::pair return value

Tags: c#, c++, clang, pinvoke

How do I make the corresponding PInvoke function declaration in C# with the returntype as a std::pair<> ?

```
std::pair<const VarDecl *, SourceLocation> getCursorVariableRef(CXCursor C);
```

Comment: You don't, C++/CLI required so the virtual destructor is properly called.  You certainly maximized the odds to make this Q+A as useless as possible to other programmers. Tsk, tsk.  If you want to tinker with LLVM then first look at the existing SharpLang and LLILC projects.

Comment: Well I need to create some legacy C p/invokes to be used by a legacy C# project. I did not want to write them manually and generate them with the Clang translator. While doing this and investigating in the legacy headers there is a function that the Clang translator considers as a VarDecl. I could not extract any info out of it besides the returntype. I was hoping that the function getCursorVariableRef could help me.

Comment: P/invoke cannot help with types like this, you'll need to find another way